# Most simple way to load content and keep it on the phone from the web? (PhoneGap)

Tags: php, json, html, cordova

I created an app with PhoneGap but I need to load some stuff from another domain. I tried jQuery load with a xdomainload plugin but It did not work.
The stuff I need to show run on PHP as the back-end language. I'm really noob - I've seen a few tutorials about JSON but all of them did not work and I ended giving up. Is JSON the easiest way?

Thank you all

Comment: Without code, there is an infinite number of ways this could have not worked. We can't help you without any sort of code.

Comment: It's simply a PHP page retrieving results from a query and I want to display it on a local mobile application

Comment: This entire thing screams of not doing any work, and instead attempting to offload that on folks on Stack Overflow. If you don't understand how JSON works, go learn how it works, then ask a _specific_ question here. Try something, document what you did, then post _that_ here. Don't come to Stack Overflow, say, "I want to make something", and then ask us to do it.

Comment: As I said, I tried learning it, however nothing of what I've done worked. If you understood that I want someone to make all the work for me, sorry, that's not what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, PHP wont run client-side in Cordova. If you're trying to access some sort of backend service that you built using PHP, then that's doable with JSON. Whether it's "the easiest", makes this question to open for interpretation. Generally speaking, a common approach may be to use javascript to communicate with backend services which "talk" JSON between each other. This question might get closed for being to opinion based. But that's my 2 cents.